# How to tweet an url as tiny url like bt.ly?

Tags: android, url, twitter, tinyurl

I have successfully integrated twitter's Oauth into my app, but anybody have an idea how to tweet an url as tiny url like bt.ly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [BitlyAndroid](https://github.com/finnjohnsen/BitlyAndroid)? However, the term is "link shortener", so maybe a search for [link shortener android api](http://www.google.com/search?q=link%20shortener%20android%20api) might help.

Comment: Thanks  Tim Büthe , ur code is very help full to me . We have done it

Answer (score 0):

I would focus on choosing one or a few URL shortener APIs and simply implement them. You can scrape your tweets for URLs and send them to the bit.ly API or the goo.gl API for shortening them.

If you have an API key with bit.ly (which you simply apply for) - you can simply call an URL and get a shortened result, such as:

```
http://api.bitly.com/v3/shorten?login=bitlyapidemo&apiKey=R_0da49e0a9118ff35f52f629d2d71bf07&longUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fbetaworks.com%2F&format=json
```

which would return:

```
{
    "status_code": 200, 
    "data": {
        "url": "http://bit.ly/cmeH01", 
        "hash": "cmeH01", 
        "global_hash": "1YKMfY", 
        "long_url": "http://betaworks.com/", 
        "new_hash": 0
    }, 
    "status_txt": "OK"
}
```

the `hash´ part is the what you put after bit.ly. So your shortened link would be: http://bit.ly/cmeH01

Other url shortener services have similar APIs.